# Visualize MySQL Database int to text with bitwise

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a column which is int. It stores user's info as flag.
I created a flag table so that some numbers correspond to some properties.

[image: Flag Table]

For example:

User's flag: 7

[image: User properties as integer]

Flag table values means:

```
1= Full account
2= Has access room1
4= Has access room2
8= Has access room2
So 7 = 1 | 2 | 4 (user has => full acc and has access room1&2)
```

I want to show all users flags as text (not integer, I mean like calculated text)(in example 7 means FULL_ACCOUNT+HAS_ACCESS_ROOM_1+HAS_ACCESS_ROOM_2)
Is this possible? Or any better way to analyse visually all users info(300+) in phpmyadmin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather messy.

```
SELECT  
    COALESCE(
      CONCAT_WS('+',
        CASE WHEN user_flag & 1 THEN 'FULL_ACCESS' END,
        CASE WHEN user_flag & 2 THEN 'HAS_ACCESS_ROOM_1' END,
        CASE WHEN user_flag & 4 THEN 'HAS_ACCESS_ROOM_2' END,
        CASE WHEN user_flag & 8 THEN 'HAS_ACCESS_ROOM_3' END ),
    'NO ACCESS')
```

Notes:

- Each bit is checked individually.
- `CASE` will see "true" if the "and" (`&`) yields any non-zero value.
- When a bit is missing, the `CASE` (without `ELSE`) generates `NULL`.
- `CONCAT_WS`, given all `NULLs`, will generate `NULL`.
- `COALESCE` turns `NULL` into `FULL_ACCESS`.
- (not used in this query) `(1<<3)` is 8.  This is a way to turn bit position into INT.
- It is theoretically possible to use `flag_table` to look up the access expressions, it would be even messier.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I don't know much about sql, do you think I should use this kind of structure or should I open 3-4 more columns and use true false which one is better in terms of usability and performance?

Comment: @Emrexdy - There are tradeoffs.  Separate columns would be bulkier -- but that won't matter unless you have a billion employees.  My query (or any other I can envision) would only take milliseconds; how often do you need to run the query?  How often might you change the bits or the "flag_table" -- hence have to chang the SELECT?  There is a hard limit of 64 bits with `BIGINT UNSIGNED` (8 bytes); `TINYINT UNSIGNED` takes 1 byte, allowing only 8 permissions.

Comment: Think of how a medium-sized company uses RFID badges -- A person may have a "role" of Regular employee, Janitor (access includes certain closets), Fire marshal (inspect everything), etc.  Then a person maps to a role(s) who maps to a set of door(s) and hence their locks.

Comment: I won't have many users so I think new columns and use true or false is best way. 
I have one more question;
Can we convert integer values to string via phpmyadmin by associating tables without running any query? Like in this question but without bit operations and without running a query? For example in another table, 10 means administrator, when i link both 2 tables, I don't want see 10. I want to see administrator. I guess I can do this with running query but is there anyway to do this without a query? Or any option like save the query and one click to run? What should I search? Thank you

Comment: If I needed that mapping (from bits to a string) in more than one place, I would write a Stored Function.  This won't help speed, but may help programming "encapsulation".  This would make it easier if I later decided to use separate columns (or whatever);

Comment: A general rule -- the database is where persistently store information.  It is not necessarily the "right" place to apply business logic.  That is, if I were writing a PHP app, I might put the bits and their interpretation in PHP code, leaving an "opaque" integer in the database.  Using a stored function is, arguably, a middle ground between burying it in some SQL somewhere versus burying it in PHP.

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a programming language.  I don't see that as a viable option.

Comment: If every person has only one bit on, then you don't need the mask, just a bit number and a simple single-row lookup in `user_flag`.  On the other hand, if a person can have any combination of 20 bits, keep in mind that there are 1048576 combinations of 20 bits.  I would go with some form of `CONCAT`.  BTW, see also `GROUP_CONCAT(x SEPARATOR '+')` -- I did not suggest it yet because the bits might need to be in an `IN(...)` list, which is alien to the original intent of your question.

Comment: For last comment; in my case user will have maximum 5 different boolean types (5 flags). 

Thank you very much! I learned new things!

Comment: Keep in mind that today there is a max of 5, but next month they will come up with a 6th.  Part of good design is planning for future changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked specifically about doing it in phpMyAdmin, I thought a bit about your options for this. Within phpMyAdmin, you can easily display foreign keys by their referenced values, but to do the result of a bitwise operation on it requires a bit more complexity. It's close, but doesn't quite capture what you're trying to express here.

There's a [transformation feature](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/transformations.html), which would allow you to write your own plugin (since nothing like this currently exists in the distribution), but if you're familiar with PHP the plugins are relatively small bits of code. There's a pretty good chance you could compute this on the command line and use the "[External](https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/index.php?route=/transformation/overview&server=1#transformation)" transformation to run some external program (a shell script, for instance) which would then cause the returned result to display in phpMyAdmin directly. This would require writing some small shell script or other program to find the correct values, but could be another solution.

The solution provided by Rick James is an excellent approach to solving this in SQL. I'll also add that this sort of logic and computation should often be done in the application; I see how it could be useful for an administrator to reference that directly from phpMyAdmin but most of the setting, changing, and viewing that value is better handled in your application.